# "Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets""

Tags: qt, cmake, build, qt5

I have been trying to build a software that uses cmake, but I don't have the necessary packages from qt5. Both " Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
qt5widgets-config.cmake" are not in the qt folder, so I need to know how I can get them.
I saw that some people solved this problem by adding this in the "cmakelist.txt": set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\msvc2010")
But this folder doesn't even exist in my computer, so I don't know exactly what to do.

[This is the error, to be more specific](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpovF.png)

I don't know if there is somewhere else where I can get this files, because by only downloading qt, this didn't help at all.

Comment: Please note, that on Stack Overflow we discourage using images for code and error messages: Instead, paste them into the question post as **text** and format accordingly. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: How did you install qt? Why is `find_package` looking in shat seems to be a directory containing the qt **sources** and not the installed build result?

Comment: @fabian I downloaded the binaries, should I try to build the sources instead?

Comment: `.../Src/qtbase/src/corelib/Qt5Config.cmake` doesn't look like something that's part of installed binaries to me...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your dlls (libraries) to the project. Qt5Widgets library comes together with the installation of qt to your computer. Many people solve it by adding this:

> CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\msvc2010"

to cmake file because qt is installed there. I am assuming that you have your qt installed already and you have a problem in debug or release build. Therefore you need to locate where you have installed qt and than add that directory to your path or cmake.

Comment: I found three files when searching for "qt5widgets" in the qt folder: "Qt5Widgets.dll,Qt5WidgetsMacros and Qt5WidgetsConfigExtras.cmake.in". Do I have to put this in the same folder as the cmake lists? Oh, and the folder msvc 2010 doesn't exist, do I have to create it?

Comment: Do you know if one of these files can help me?

Comment: For your second question msvc 2010 should be installed from the internet and then set to path (ideally via a script that initalizes all these paths). the dlls that you have found also should be visable by your program by adding the directory to the path